# Convert number to percentage

Tags: c#

How can i convert this value so that instead of looking like .3572, it appears as 35.72% in the output?

So what i'm trying to do is display this as a percentage in the output of a console program.
Tax is a float

Tax is the just the percentage value itself, to use the value in an equation i'm using the variable below. Then i have the value show up in the console through the writeline.
But it keeps coming up as .3572.

```
tax = 35.72f 

var taxPercentage = tax / 100;
Console.WriteLine("Tax Rate" + taxPercentage.ToString());
```

Comment: How would i add 
    String.Format("Value: {0:P2}.", 0.8526) // formats as 85.26 % (varies by culture), 
 to my current line?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Tax Rate {0:0.00}%", (taxPercentage * 100));` maybe? ^_^;

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
Console.WriteLine("Tax Rate {0}", taxPercentage.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**note**

At the top of your source file you have to add this using statement:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, pretty new to c#, when i try putting that in, it comes up with this: Error The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: you welcome dude. What's the error? I just saw it.

Comment: @bj443 please let me know, if now you got that you wanted.

Comment: Yea thankyou, but it just comes up with a space between the value and the % sign so
    35.72 %, rather than 35.72%

Comment: i ended up using this,   Console.WriteLine("Tax Rate                    " + tax.ToString("P")); (where "tax" is 0.3572  it comes to the same effect as your answer, but i still get the extra space between the value and the % sign.

Comment: You could try this one  `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))` inside the `ToString` method. Please let me know if that works. Thanks.

Comment: yea that just gets rid of the % sign, i think when you use "P" in ToString, it inherently leaves a space inbetween.

Comment: @bj443 no it doesn't. It depends on the Culture you have specified. For instance if `double number = .2468013;`, then `Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` displays 24.68 %, this `Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hr-HR")));` displays 24,68%  and this `Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("P1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` displays 24.7 %. i have taken this exampels from MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ok fair enough, it's just for class we're only supposed to be using System;, so i think the task is to sort of get through it without using seperate cultures

Comment: yea the example displays the value with 24,67%, but it's a comma rather than a fullstop. (sorry if i'm coming off rude, some stuff is just a little hard to understand)

Comment: @bj443 you haven't to apologize. All this stuff are cultrue related. Doing a little google reasearch for finding the specific culture you want is that you need. Just let me know if you need any more help Thanks